# vscode sass color preview not working

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

I don't have that little box that shows the color as shown in the [official website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css#_syntax-coloring-color-preview)

Comment: Assuming your file is recognized as less, sass or css, do you have "css.colorDecorators.enable": false  in your settings?

Comment: Is the color stored in a variable? Because vscode does not do this for sass vars.

Comment: I found the same issue fir sass file. In my vscode's settings, it is "css.colorDecorators.enable": true and "scss.colorDecorators.enable": true; but the color box is missing. My vscode version is 1.12.2

Comment: I have the same issue :(

Comment: any luck finding a solution?

Comment: This applies only to Sass files. CSS and Scss are fine. Note that the documentation does not contain any screenshots of such support for Sass.

Answer (score 0):

I don't found native solve, but found replace with extension. This extension doesn't have color picker.

**Temprorary solve**

1. Install extension:
   [Color Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=naumovs.color-highlight)
2. If you want work this extension only  **in .sass** file format
   <kbd>CTR + SHIFT + P</kbd> ->
   <kbd>Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)</kbd> -> 
   Replace this: 
   **`"color-highlight.languages": ["*"]`**  to **`"color-highlight.languages": ["sass"]`**

[User settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMwQ6.png)